# Java layer on Android SDK supports connection through IPv6 link local address?

Tags: android, ipv6

I am not able to connect Android client running on 3.0 HoneyComb to 
server sending IPv6 packet having Link-local IPv6 address.

Does JAVA layer on android supports connection using link-local 
address for IPv6?.

Comment: I am not sure as Google guys mentioned IPv6 support is available on Android 1.6 or up , but i checked with 2.2 it even does not have link local IPv6 address whereas 3.0 has that.
 
I tried to set up an environment to generate gloabal IPv6 but DHCP can assign IPv6 to other client except 3.0 HoneyComb which may have bug in native code ?.
 
When i got gloabal IPv6 address from server i still not able to connect it says network unreachable ?.
 
 
Any suggestion